# How to change this format using curl php

Tags: php, curl

I want change this format become using `curl` in PHP
from this format

```php
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => "https://trythis.co.id/api/android/iki_bank/fcm",
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array('memberid' => '58108982293','title' => 'samu'),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    "Content-Type: application/json",
    "Authorization: asdasIjoxNadNZ6JI"
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

to this format

```php
$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com");
```

Comment: Any particular reason why?

Answer (score -1):

I hope this helps pls dont forget to mark the answer as correct if it helps you:

```
$url = "WRITE HERE YOUR URL";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 4);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
if (!$response) {
    echo curl_error($ch);
}
```